# How to use xsl:if for the following?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<From>
<Name>AEROLIA SAS</Name>-
<TaxIdentifier>-
    <ExternalReference>
        <SystemReference>BA01</SystemReference>
        <Identifier>34288174</Identifier>
    </ExternalReference>
    <ExternalReference>
        <SystemReference>Airbus Global</SystemReference>
        <Identifier>288174</Identifier>
    </ExternalReference>
</TaxIdentifier>
</From>
```

I need to be able to select the value `288174` if `SystemReference='Airbus Global'`. I am currently trying to do it the following way:

```
<xsl:if test="From/TaxIdentifier/ExternalReference/SystemReference=Airbus Global">
```

But it's obviously wrong. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need if, try this xpath selector

```
From/TaxIdentifier/ExternalReference[SystemReference='Airbus Global']/Identifier
```